# Create folders dynamically for scheduled reports

Tags: vbscript, reporting-services

Is there any way to create dynamic folders in a SSRS 2005 scheduled job?

I have SSRS reports deployed which are scheduled to run every month. These reports need to be created in dynamic folders (path can be retrieved from the table using SP). That part is done, but the issue is it needs to have the folder pre-created in destination.

Folder structure:

```
  +---Consolidated
        |   \---Product
        |       +---Drive Technologies
        |       |   +---ANEMA
        |       |   +---LD Special Motor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an option built into SSRS which can accomplish this. You could create your own extensions for SSRS, but I think the easiest and cleanest path would be to create a script (powershell?) that runs independently and creates the folders. I would also have this script move the reports as needed. Then there would be no need for data-driven subscriptions (= Enterprise Edition SQL) or some other SSRS hackery.